# Secure Socket.io and React Native doesn't work anymore

Tags: javascript, react-native, socket.io

My issue is simple, when i'm trying to connect to my socket.io server on http, it's working.

But when i'm trying to connect to a secure server, it's not working, but it worked 1 months ago, and not now, i don't know why ...

That's my code :

```js
import io from 'socket.io-client';

let socket = io("https://foo.bar:12345", {
    secure: true,
    transports: ['websocket'],
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    query: "authid=test"
});

socket.on("connect", (args) => {
    console.log("Received Event connect---> ", args);
})
socket.on("error", (args) => {
    console.log("Received Event error ---> ", args);
})
socket.on("connect_error", (args) => {
    console.log("Received Event connect_error ---> ", args);
})
```

It's **important to precise**, my code is **working perfectly on node**, but **not on react-native**, and i have this error :

```html
Received Event connect_error --->  Error: websocket error
    at WS.Transport.onError (transport.js:64)
    at WebSocket.ws.onerror (websocket.js:150)
    at WebSocket.dispatchEvent (event-target.js:172)
    at WebSocket.js:266
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:179)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:351)
    at MessageQueue.js:116
    at MessageQueue.__guardSafe (MessageQueue.js:314)
    at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (MessageQueue.js:115)
    at debuggerWorker.js:70
```

Thank your for your help ... ;)

EDIT: I have tested on another PC, with the same code, without recompiling and it's working ... Oo Why it is not working with my PC ? I've reset metro cache, no change !

Comment: Did you manage to fix this issue?

Comment: Sorry for the delay ! But yes i have fixed, it was an issue with the certificate server side, not the good file. I have changed and it worked !